# Special solution to the Sylvester equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, sylvester-equation

I'm focusing on this particular kind of Sylvester's equation:
\begin{equation}AX=XA^\dagger\end{equation}
where I would like that the solution $X$ defines an inner product, namely it is Hermitian and positive semidefinite. The size of $A$ is around 100, so the Kronecker product trick runs very slow. I would like to know if there is a special algorithm to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *“I would like that the solution $X$ defines an inner product, namely it is Hermitian and positive semidefinite.”*

It isn’t clear whether you want $X$ to be positive *definite* or positive semidefinite. If $X$ is merely positive semidefinite, it only defines a *semi-inner* product, not necessarily an inner product.

If you want $X$ to be positive definite, note that $AX=XA^\dagger$ implies that $A=HX^{-1}$ for some Hermitian matrix $H$. Hence $A$ must be similar to the Hermitian matrix $X^{-1/2}HX^{-1/2}$. In other words, the equation is solvable only if $A$ is a diagonalisable matrix with a real spectrum. If this is the case, let $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ be a diagonalisation. Then $X=PP^\dagger$ is a solution.

If you only want $X$ to be positive semidefinite, you may take $X=0$.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is suprisingly simple to me. May I aks that if $X(X^{-1})^\dagger=1$ is a general property of positive definite matrices where you have implicitly used?

Comment: @user835469 Sorry, but I haven't used $X(X^{-1})^\dagger$ anywhere in my answer. Which part in my answer are you referring to?

Comment: By substituting $A=HX^{-1}$ into $AX=XA^\dagger$ I obtain $HX^{-1}X=X(X^{-1})^\dagger H^\dagger$.

Comment: @user835469 $X(X^{-1})^\dagger=X(X^\dagger)^{-1}=XX^{-1}=I$.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks a lot, I always forget that the two operations commute.